# Index different type of documents using Solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr4

I need to index different type of JSON documents, each JSON document can be in any format, may have nested JSON objects(don't have the control). Once the indexing is done should be able to search. Since we don't have the control on JSON document schema or format decided to go with schemaless option. Got stuck with the following issues:

- All the values are getting converted to list because of the configurations  in the updateProcessor 'AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory'.

  - Ex: String datatype is mapped to text_general, it's set multiValued = true.
  - If I define the field in the managed-schema, then it's fine.
  - Input: `{"firstname":"ASGASGKSAJHAJS"}` Output: `{"firstname":["ASGASGKSAJHAJS"]}`

All nested documents are converting to flat structure

`{"firstname":"ASGASGKSAJHAJS", "address":{"addressLine1":"4216 jshakjfhajh"}}`is getting converted to
`{"firstname":"ASGASGKSAJHAJS", "address.addressLine1":"4216 jshakjfhajh"}`

I'm trying to index blindly any type(ex: JSON format) of document. When I search expecting the response in the format same as the request(at the time of indexing) with minimal Solr config changes. For now, I'm dealing with JSON only, next requirement to index PDF. For my use case, Solr is the right choice or should I look at the other options?

I'm new to Solr, gone through the documentation & articles, don't find any simplest way to overcome the above issues. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are trying to do this with "minimal Solr config changes" as you said, then Solr is very likely not the best fit for you. However, if you are willing to spend the time to customize Solr and/or your JSON to be ingested properly Solr might be a good fit.

Comment: Hi @HectorCorrea, thanks for the response. So far, I've done the following i.e. for the first issue, by using the Java reflection API & Solr Rest API I'm creating/defining the fields. For the second issue, once I get the Solr query response, I'm unflattening the JSON object by using Java third-party library. Is there a better solution for the second issue. I'm new to Solr, interested to learn and implement the solution, looking for some guidance.